# Extract (repeating) groups containing parentheses using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

My string :

```
(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3
```

Desired result (key/value pair):

```
(01)    this is value one  
(02)    and this is 2   
(03)    and this is number 3
```

My code so far:

```
$s="(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3" 
$pattern  = '(\(\d\d\))(.*)' 
$m = $s | select-string $pattern -AllMatches | % {$_.matches} | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want the key names to be `(##)` or `##`? the 2nd will be simpler to use since it would not require handling the `()` ... [*grin*]

Comment: the 2nd. Just ##

Comment: thanks! that will be noticeably easier to deal with.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey : Can you provide me a sample?

Comment: yep! [*grin*] just added an alternate answer to the list of answers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **you're looking for *key-value pairs***, it makes sense to **collect them in a(n ordered) *hashtable***.

Splitting can be performed via the regex-based **`-split` operator**, which also allows including parts of what the *separator* regex matches in the output array, via capture groups (`(...)`).

```
# Input string
$s = '(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3'

# Initialize the output hashtable
$ht = [ordered] @{}

# Split the input string and fill the hashtable.
$i = 0; 
$s -split '(\(\d+\)) ' -ne '' | ForEach-Object { 
  if (++$i % 2) { $key = $_ } else { $ht[$key] = $_ }
}

# Output the hashtable
$ht
```

The above yields:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
(01)                           this is value one 
(02)                           and this is 2 
(03)                           and this is number 3
```

Note: If you don't want to include the enclosing `(...)` in the key (name) properties, use 
`-split '\((\d+)\) '` instead of `-split '(\(\d+\)) '`

The above splits the string into the elements of an array in which pairs of adjacent elements represent key-value pairs. The `ForEach-Object` call then adds these key-value pairs to the output hashtable, deciding if the input element is a key or a value based on whether the element index is odd or even.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your regex `'(\(\d\d\))(.*)'` is too *greedy*, meaning that a single match on a given line will match the *entire* line due to the `.*` sub-expression.

You'll get the desired matches if you use the following regex instead:
`'(\(\d+\)) ([^(]+)'`

That is, after matching an index such as `(01)` only match up to but not including the subsequent `(`, if any.

In the context of a **streamlined version of your original command**, which **outputs the key-value pairs as an array of *custom objects*** (`[pscustomobject]` instances):

```
$s = '(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3'
$pattern  = '(\(\d+\)) ([^(]+)'
$s | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {
  $_.matches | Select-Object @{ n='Name';  e = { $_.Groups[1].Value } },
                             @{ n='Value'; e = { $_.Groups[2].Value } }
}
```

The above yields:

```
Name Value
---- -----
(01) this is value one 
(02) and this is 2 
(03) and this is number 3
```

Do note, however, that the above outputs an *array* of *custom objects* that each represent a key-value pair, which differs from the solution in the top section, which creates a single hashtable containing all key-value pairs.

Comment: My pleasure, @JohnDoe; glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve your desired output with the following:

```
PS H:\> $pattern = '(\(\d\d\))([^(]*)'
PS H:\> $results = $s | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Value
(01) this is value one
(02) and this is 2
(03) and this is number 3
```

Edit: Accessing match groups:

```
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Captures.Groups[0].value
(01) this is value one
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Captures.Groups[1].value
(01)
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Captures.Groups[2].value
 this is value one
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Captures.Groups[3].value
(02) and this is 2
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Captures.Groups[4].value
(02)
PS H:\> $results.Matches.Captures.Groups[5].value
 and this is 2
```

Comment: Many thanks. Can I split them in groups? To access them by group. e.g group[1]=(01) and group[2]=this is value one etc.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've updated my answer with a slightly different regex to work with your original code. That work?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but access them by group. e.g group[1]=(01) and group[2]=this is value one etc.

Comment: My bad, I see what you mean. Yeah, you can iterate through the groups, as you can see in my edit, the groups will be the whole match and then the individual captures.

Comment: Sorry but I've a different result using your code. 
 the result for `$results.Matches.Captures.Groups[1].value` is `(02) and this is 2` I'd like to end up with a dictionary - key-value pair for every line

Comment: @JohnDoe I apologize, I restored the regex back to its initial version when I made that edit. It should be accurate now, I just reproduced it line by line.

Comment: Yes, but the accepted answer is more close to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

here's an alternate method that uses string methods instead of regex. it also stores the output in an ordered hashtable. the `[ordered]` is merely for convenience - i wanted the display to be in sequence so that i could confirm the output was as expected.

rewrote the "blank items" filter to use `Where-Object` instead of `.Where()` since the OP is on a pre-v4 version of PoSh.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3
(01) One Bravo (03) Three Bravo
(02) Two Charlie
(111) OneThrice Delta (666) Santa Delta
(01) One Echo (03) Three Echo (05) Five Echo
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$LookupTable = [ordered]@{}

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # OP cannot use the ".Where()" array method - that was added in ps4
    #foreach ($Split_Item in $IS_Item.Split('(').Where({$_}))
    $Split_ISI = $IS_Item.Split('(') |
        # this gets rid of the empty items
        Where-Object {$_}

    foreach ($SI_Item in $Split_ISI)
        {
        $Key = $SI_Item.Split(')')[0].Trim()
        $Value = $SI_Item.Split(')')[1].Trim()
        # the leading comma forces the input to be an array
        $LookupTable[$Key] += ,$Value
        }
    }

$LookupTable | Out-Host

$LookupTable['01'][0] | Out-Host
$LookupTable['02'][1] | Out-Host
```

output ...

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
01                             {this is value one, One Bravo, One Echo}
02                             {and this is 2, Two Charlie}
03                             {and this is number 3, Three Bravo, Three Echo}
111                            {OneThrice Delta}
666                            {Santa Delta}
05                             {Five Echo}


this is value one
Two Charlie
```

the main gotcha here is that the lookup key MUST be a string, so the digits must be quoted for a direct lookup - `'01'` instead of `01`.

Comment: I get an error when I run your code: `Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'Where'.
At line:15 char:29
+     foreach ($Split_Item in $IS_Item.Split('(').Where({$_}))
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: @JohnDoe - that indicates that `$IS_Item.Split('(')` did not produce the expected array, OR that you are using a version of PS that doesn't support `.Where()`. [1] what is in `$IS_Item` at that point? [2] what version of PoSh are you running?

Comment: `$IS_Item` contains `(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3` and PoSh version is: `PSVersion    3.0`, `CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000`, `BuildVersion 6.2.9200.22198`

Comment: @JohnDoe - ah! the `.Where()` array method was introduced in v4. i will go back and rewrite that to use the pipeline & `Where-Object`. otta have it tested and posted to the answer in little bit. ///// as an aside, if at all possible, try to get updated to the current version of PoSh - v5.1 on windows.

Comment: @JohnDoe - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Taking the 4 spaces following the `(xx)` literal

```
$s="(01) this is value one (02) and this is 2 (03) and this is number 3"
$s -replace " (?=\(\d\d\))","`n" -replace "(?<=\(\d\d\)) +","   "
```

Sample output:

```
(01)    this is value one
(02)    and this is 2
(03)    and this is number 3
```

The above RegEx uses zero length lookarounds

- the first replacing the leading space with a CR
- the second one replacing any number of trailing spaces against exactly 4.